# what relationship between Maistra and Istio

Tags: istio

I am very confused what relationship between Maistra and Istio?

I view their github repository, and be always confused which one is parent project, which one is derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maistra is an opinionated distribution of Istio designed to work with Openshift.

Source: https://maistra.io/

In other words: Maistra is a clone of Istio, configured in a way that it fits best for an Openshift environment. They have a dedicated page where maistra is compared with istio, that states:

> The modifications to Maistra are sometimes necessary to resolve issues, provide additional features, or to handle differences **when deploying on OpenShift or OKD**.

Source: https://maistra.io/docs/comparison-with-istio/

So you can think of Istio (https://istio.io) as the parent istio main project and Maistra as an Istio project dedicated for OpenShift deployment.

And thus https://github.com/istio/istio is the parent project and https://github.com/maistra/istio is derived from it in some way.